Invoke nonexistent __new__ method for abstract class: What happens?
I was trying to decipher the following code, executed in a Conda environment for Python 3.9:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
# <...snip...>
current_file_start_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

Here is the source code for datetime.py that I found online.  The timezone class starts as follows:
class timezone(tzinfo):
    __slots__ = '_offset', '_name'

    # Sentinel value to disallow None
    _Omitted = object()
    def __new__(cls, offset, name=_Omitted):
        if not isinstance(offset, timedelta):
            raise TypeError("offset must be a timedelta")
        if name is cls._Omitted:
            if not offset:
                return cls.utc
            name = None
        elif not isinstance(name, str):
            raise TypeError("name must be a string")
        if not cls._minoffset <= offset <= cls._maxoffset:
            raise ValueError("offset must be a timedelta "
                             "strictly between -timedelta(hours=24) and "
                             "timedelta(hours=24).")
        return cls._create(offset, name)

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, offset, name=None):
        self = tzinfo.__new__(cls)
        self._offset = offset
        self._name = name
        return self

# <...snip...>

timezone.utc = timezone._create(timedelta(0))

The __new__ method invokes _create, which in turn invokes tzinfo.__new__.  Fortunately, the tzinfo class is defined in the same datetime.py, but it is self documented as an abstract base class and doesn't have a __new__ method.

Does the tzinfo not have a __new__ method because it is an abstract class and (I presume) can't be instantiated?

What happens when tzinfo.__new__ is called, as above?



tzinfo does have a new method.  voting to close as unclear what you're asking ...

@wim: Your comment makes sense, but only after the information in Daniel Walker's answer.

Please edit the mis-info out of the question, at least- tzinfo() can be instantiated and is not really an abstract base class, despite what the source says (the comment seems to indicate that this type is only intended to be subclassed, it's misleading).

I added "I presume" before the comment that it can't be instantiated.  Really, that was part of my question.  On your point about tzinfo not being an abstract base class, can you please clarify?  I cite the source code, and the first line in the defintion of tzinfo is a comment that it is an abstract base class.

tzinfo is an quasi-abstract base class in the sense that it has multiple explicitly unimplemented methods, but it predates the abc module and has never been updated to prevent someone from instantiating it. (abc was introduced in Python 2.6; datetime.tzinfo was introduced in Python 2.3.)

"Intended to be subclassed" means that a direct instance of tzinfo is unlikely to work as expected. The documented methods raise NotImplementedErrors, rather than providing useful information about its argument.

Thanks, @chepner.  I also found this Q&A.  Since abstract classes were a concept befor it was formalized as ABC in Python, it seems to me that tzinfo still qualifies as an abstract class (the concept), even if it doesn't use the Python formalization.  It might help if the formalized ABC was referred to as a proper name (i.e. capitalized as Abstract Base Class) and the concept used lower case (abstract base class) so that people are on the same page when discussing it.  But that's a different discussion.

My question refers to tzinfo as an abstract class (no word "base"), so I'm not referring to the formalized ABC, of which I was not aware.  On the other hand, I do point out that the documentation string describes it as an abstract base class, which is true.  I now realize that it is referring to the concept rather than the formalization, which came later.

@chepner said: "The documented methods raise NotImplementedErrors, rather than providing useful information about its argument". I understand that point. I would say that the raised error is still useful information, but not ideal, hence the formalization of ABC. Before ABC, however, that was how abstract base classes were coded.

All classes inherit from object and object provides the __new__ class method.  datetime.timezone is overriding that but tzinfo uses the inherited method.

Thank you, @Daniel Walker.  For the less savvy would-be Pythoners like myself, here is what I found about the default __new__ method.

Also, dir('tzinfo') reveals a __new__ method.

Yes, it does.  I'm not sure why I didn't mark it as such, even though I upvoted it.
